# What is dua-e-noor?

Tags: salat, sunnah, dua, fajr

What is dua of noor and when did Prophet Mohammad (P.B.U.H) recite this dua? And what are the exact words of this dua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: In the name of Allah, Most Beneficent, Most Merciful]

There is no Dua named as Dua-Noor in the Hadith or Qur'an. The nearest possible match that you are talking about is the Dua in which Holy Prophet (ﷺ) has prayed to Allah asking for light in various things.

> #### [Sahih Muslim 763 j](http://sunnah.com/muslim/6/225), [Sunan Abi Dawud 1353](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/5/104), [Sahih Muslim 763 a](http://sunnah.com/muslim/6/216), etc.
>
> اللَّهُمَّ اجْعَلْ فِي قَلْبِي نُورًا وَفِي بَصَرِي نُورًا وَفِي سَمْعِي نُورًا وَعَنْ يَمِينِي نُورًا وَعَنْ يَسَارِي نُورًا وَفَوْقِي نُورًا وَتَحْتِي نُورًا وَأَمَامِي نُورًا وَخَلْفِي نُورًا وَعَظِّمْ لِي نُورًا
>
> O Allah, place light in my heart, light in my tongue, light in my hearing, light in my eyesight, light on my right hand, light on my left hand, light in front of me, light behind me, light below me, O Allah, give me abundant light.

This is the nearest match of Dua-e-Noor that you are asking about.

Just [Google for Dua-e-noor](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=dua+noor) and you get a plenty of versions. These are not wrong to recite or include in your supplications but these originate from sources other than Qur'an or Ahaadith and hence the so-called virtues and merits of it are not proved from hadith.

> - [Fatwa at Darul Iftaah.](http://darulifta-deoband.org/showuserview.do?function=answerView&all=en&id=33267)
> - [Answer by Mufti Ibrahim Desai](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/16101)

One thing to remember is to go through the meaning of the Dua you recite so that there are no elements of [Shirk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shirk_%28Islam%29) in it.

#### ۚ  وَاللَّهُ عَلِيمٌ حَكِيمٌ (And Allah is the All-Knower, the Wise)

#### اللَّهُمَّ انْفَعْنِي بِمَا عَلَّمْـتَنِي وَ عَلِّمْنِي مَا يَنْفَعُنِي

Answer (score 1):

Dua of noor is a prayer that the Prophet (SAW) once read. He read it after performing the 2 sunnah rakaahs of Fajr prayer. Then, he left his house, and on the way to the mosque, he prayed the prayer. The words are:

> اللَّهُمَّ اجْعَلْ فِي قَلْبِي نُورًا وَفِي بَصَرِي نُورًا وَفِي سَمْعِي نُورًا وَفِي لِسَانِي نُورًا وَعَنْ يَمِينِي نُورًا وَعَنْ يَسَارِي نُورًا , اللَّهُمَّ وَاجْعَلْ مِنْ فَوْقِي نُورًا وَمِنْ تَحْتِي نُورًا وَاجْعَلْ أَمَامِي نُورًا وَمِنْ خَلْفِي نُورًا , اللَّهُمَّ وَأَعْظِمْ لِي نُورًا "

Translation:

> O Allah! put noor in my heart, in my sight, in my hearing, in my speech, on my right, on my left, above me, from under me, in front of me, and behind me. O Allah! Make the noor strong for me.

The word *noor* is often translated as light and can also be interpreted as guidance/ direction / help/ support.

The full hadith is:

> (حديث مرفوع) حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو مُحَمَّدٍ يَحْيَى بْنُ مُحَمَّدِ بْنِ صَاعِدٍ الْهَاشِمِيُّ بِبَغْدَادَ ، حَدَّثَنَا الْحَسَنُ بْنُ عَرَفَةَ ، حَدَّثَنَا هُشَيْمٌ ، عَنْ حُصَيْنِ بْنِ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ ، عَنْ حَبِيبِ بْنِ أَبِي ثَابِتٍ ، عَنْ مُحَمَّدِ بْنِ عَلِيِّ بْنِ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ عَبَّاسٍ ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ ، عَنْ جَدِّهِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ ، قَالَ : بِتُّ ذَاتَ لَيْلَةٍ عِنْدَ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ فَصَلَّى رَكْعَتَيِ الْفَجْرِ وَخَرَجَ إِلَى الصَّلاةِ وَهُوَ يَقُولُ : " اللَّهُمَّ اجْعَلْ فِي قَلْبِي نُورًا وَفِي بَصَرِي نُورًا وَفِي سَمْعِي نُورًا وَفِي لِسَانِي نُورًا وَعَنْ يَمِينِي نُورًا وَعَنْ يَسَارِي نُورًا , اللَّهُمَّ وَاجْعَلْ مِنْ فَوْقِي نُورًا وَمِنْ تَحْتِي نُورًا وَاجْعَلْ أَمَامِي نُورًا وَمِنْ خَلْفِي نُورًا , اللَّهُمَّ وَأَعْظِمْ لِي نُورًا " قَالَ : فَأَقَامَ بِلالٌ الصَّلاةَ فَصَلَّى .

source: http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=517&hid=71&pid=129538

Answer (score 1):

I have posted the link that further transliterates the Duaa. I always wanted to know the meaning of what I am reciting, this page will help you. YOu can copy and paste or download the file. 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Sb-Up1VdH7RTyFuSwdV6lUNJxSl5MB-i0yq-qAHFMrM/edit?usp=sharing 
May Allah Bless All!!!